# Msg 2627, occured while using IDENT_CURRENT()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE OSOBA
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY not null IDENTITY,
    imie VARCHAR(30) not null,
    nazwisko VARCHAR(40) not null,
    zawod VARCHAR(30) not null,
    dataUrodzenia DATE,
    plec BIT not null,
    narodowosc VARCHAR(30) not null,
);

CREATE TABLE OSOBISTOSCI
(
    nazwaMiasta VARCHAR(30) not null,
    id INT not null,
    adres VARCHAR(50),
    czy BIT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES OSOBA,
    FOREIGN KEY (nazwaMiasta) REFERENCES MIASTA,
);

CREATE TABLE ARCHITEKCI
(
    id INT not null,
    uprawnienia VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,
    styl VARCHAR(30) not null,
    liczba INT not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES OSOBA,
);
```

And I have these insert statements:

```
-- these work fine
INSERT INTO OSOBA (imie,nazwisko,zawod,dataUrodzenia,plec,narodowosc) VALUES ('Lech', 'Wałęsa', 'Elektryk', '19430129', 1, 'Polak');
INSERT INTO OSOBISTOSCI (nazwaMiasta, id, adres, czy) VALUES ('Gdańsk', IDENT_CURRENT('OSOBA'), 'ul. Polanki', 0);

-- these throw the below error message
INSERT INTO OSOBA (imie,nazwisko,zawod,dataUrodzenia,plec,narodowosc) VALUES ('Marcia','Frank','Architekt','19570720','0','Niemiec');
INSERT INTO ARCHITEKCI (id,styl,liczba) VALUES (IDENT_CURRENT('OSOBA'),'Nowoczesny',8);
```

Error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 124
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_*ARCHITEK*_982D973E2BA18BE7'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ARCHITEKCI'. The duplicate key value is ().

Comment: What does "did't work" mean? Did you get an error message? If so, what was the text (we don't tend to memorize error numbers like 2627). Also, why are you using IDENT_CURRENT for this at all? This is not safe from concurrency - the IDENT_CURRENT you read my get incremented by some other user in between those two inserts. You should use SCOPE_IDENTITY() or, better yet, the OUTPUT clause.

Comment: Thanks for providing the error message - the DDL provided throws an error message due to missing table `MIASTA`. Please provide that table definition or remove the foreign key from the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Aaron mentioned the IDENT_CURRENT is not very reliable. It would be better to use an [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause. See the following example:

```
DECLARE @LatestID TABLE (ID INT);
INSERT INTO #OSOBA (imie,nazwisko,zawod,dataUrodzenia,plec,narodowosc) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @LatestID
VALUES ('Marcia','Frank','Architekt','19570720','0','Niemiec');

INSERT INTO #ARCHITEKCI (id,styl,liczba) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM @LatestID),'Nowoczesny',8);
```